# Venue search with query by using more than one word in foursquare

Tags: java, android, foursquare

I'm trying to learn foursquare api in java and I'm stuck at this point. Is it possible to put more than one word as "query" ? Because I'm trying to get query words from EditText and when I write for instance "Göze Teras", I'm getting this error. By the way "ö" is not giving error, I tired "o" and still getting the same error.

```
03-16 16:51:55.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1517): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal
character in query at index 63: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search? 
ll=39,35&query=Göze Teras&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&v=20140315
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake, I just used URLEncoder and everything is perfect.

```
String search = URLEncoder.encode(placename.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
```